# Não consigo diminuir o tamanho do arquivo APK

Tags: xamarin-forms, apk

Preciso gerar o APK do meu app em Xamarin fForms, mas quando marco a opção de vinculação "Somente Assenblies de SDK" para diminuir o APK, eu tomo o erro "Falha Inesperada da Tarefa 'LinkAssemblies'". Desmarcando essa opção eu consigo gerar normalmente, mas ele fica com 40 mb.

Alguém sabe o motivo desta mensagem ou se não é isso que fará com que o tamanho do meu APK diminua?

Answer (score 0):

Tive esse problema. 
Resolvi criando um projeto novo e "copiando" sua configuração e depois mudando pra "SDK Assemblies Only".

Comment: Isso é quase 1 dia de trabalho, eu já fiz isso que você falou por outros motivos similares, o Xamarin dá bug de mais... até desanima.
Se nada mais der certo vou fazer isso de novo.

Comment: Estranho, cara. Aqui Xamarin roda bem tranquilo. Mas não trabalho com Forms, apenas com Android.

Comment: Só ressaltando, que depois que você faz upload pra Google Play, a própria 
Google diminui o tamanho do apk. Ela faz esse Assemblies Only.

Comment: Bom saber Diego, eu vou tentar subir direto pra Play Store para ver.
Detalhe, acho que a zica esta no meu VS... criei um projeto novo como você falou, só que antes de perder tempo montando minha solução inteira eu ja tentei gerar o APK logo de cara. e tomei o mesmo erro  sem ter adicionado absolutamente nenhuma referencia.
Falha inesperada de tarefa "LinkAssemblies" Deixando a vinculação com "Nenhum" , a aplicação compila.
Complicado viu...